# Make first observation the variable name

Tags: loops, variables, foreach, rename, stata

I currently have a data set with 37 variables. I read in the data with `import excel` but what should be the variable names were read in as the first observation.

I want to use a loop to move the first observation to the variable names.

This is what I have tried:

```
foreach var of varlist * {
rename `A' `=`District'[1]'
}
```

District is what should be the name of the first variable but is read as the first observation.

The error I get is:

```
syntax error
    Syntax is
        rename  oldname    newname   [, renumber[(#)] addnumber[(#)] sort ...]
        rename (oldnames) (newnames) [, renumber[(#)] addnumber[(#)] sort ...]
        rename  oldnames              , {upper|lower|proper}
```

but I am not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: No need for a loop. You just have to use the `firstrow` option of the `import excel` command.

Comment: Here's a principle: you can't get anything out of a `local` macro that has not been defined.

Comment: Also see [excel import csv with headers](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+import+csv+with+headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pearly Spencer's comment is the best solution. Just do the `import` correctly!

Meanwhile, let's fix your loop:

You have

```
foreach var of varlist * {
    rename `A' `=`District'[1]'
}
```

Here the local macros `A` and `District` aren't (obviously) defined. Even if they were defined, at most this loop would  `rename` one variable by the first value of the same or another variable. The loop would fail second time round, as the variable has already been `rename`d.

What you were reaching for, I guess, was more like

```
foreach var of varlist * {
    rename `var' `=`var'[1]'
}
```

to be followed by

```
drop in 1 
destring, replace
```

if the `rename`s worked.

The revised loop is Stata code for

```
!!! not Stata 
for each variable { 
    use the value in the first observation as the new name 
}
```

Note that we are presuming that what's in the first observation is a set of distinct and legal Stata variable names. That is often a strong assumption for data files prepared outside Stata.

This code is more robust to problematic names:

```
foreach var of varlist * {
    rename `var' `=strtoname(`var'[1])'
```

}

For more, see `help strtoname()`.

If this isn't the answer you will need to give us a data example.